# R could no find the function SPARQL although I installed the package SPARQL. Why is it?

Tags: r, sparql

Here is the code I entered:

```
install.packages('SPARQL')
qq <- 'SELECT * WHERE { ?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Philosopher> . ?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/influenced> ?influenced. }'

data <- SPARQL(url="http://dbpedia.org/sparql",query=qq)
```

to which I get the following error message:

> Error: could not find function "SPARQL"

Why couldn't R recognize the function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run:

`library(SPARQL)`

Or do:

`data <- SPARQL::SPARQL(url="http://dbpedia.org/sparql",query=qq)`

Comment: Now it works! Thank you!
But what is the difference between library and install.packages? I believed they were interchangeable.

Comment: I think you're thinking of `library` and `require`, which are (pretty much) interchangeable. `install.packages` gets the R package from the CRAN server and literally installs it on your machine, so you don't need to run this every time. `library` and `require` loads the package. Run `?library` and `?install.packages` for more info :)